# How can I turn off Vue Force Dev plugin in production

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-devtools

I have a VueJS (V2) based application, I have Vue Devtools turned off in production however there is a chrome addon called Vue Force Dev available here: https://github.com/hzmming/vue-force-dev that can force dev tools even on production apps. You can see it in the Github ReadMe for VueJs.org which is Vue's prod site.

This opens up a huge security hole in my app, I don't want anyone have ability to see the state of the app. Someone can potentially reverse engineer and cause harm.

I use Vue CLI to build which automatically turns off vue devtools in production. The official Vue Devtools addon does not work however the Vue Force Dev does work.

I also tried adding following to my main.js but its the same result

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.debug = false
Vue.config.silent = true
```

Below is VueJS.org's current prod site as of today. I was able to use the devtools on the site using the addon.

[image]

Comment: that is normal for vuejs, you cant stop that. So, you have to choose carefully what information shouldn't be passed to the front end. Any backend you're using?

Comment: no frontend is ever truly "secure". devtools only makes snooping easier.  even if you could disable the extension, it's not possible to completely hide your internal state from someone dedicated enough to figuring it out.

Comment: So yeah, this extension does not do anything that somebody could already do (without the extension). You should design your app accordingly so that nothing critical happens when people can inspect the whole state of your app. This is the whole point of doing Front-end, nothing is secure there by default because sent to the client. As for the Algolia key, it is probably supposed to be public (I assume), otherwise you need a proxy (/backend) of some sort to hide it!